# Ideal and unequivocal date format for import to Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Our software is used by folks around the world, so their PC's run different locales which particularly affects the presentation of dates.  I need to export from our software a file to be imported into Excel by those users.

Now, bear in mind that different locales display dates in different formats - for example in the UK its is dd/mm/yy and the US has mm/dd/yy.  I want the date data to appear to the users who load the file in their own locale format. But I need to write the files out of my system in a standard manner. So I can't write a format sympathetic to the locale of the recipient.

I am assuming that excel reads date data, and converts it to a display format for the locale setting of the viewer.

What is the clear and [unequivocal](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unequivocal) data format to write dates into a file that will import into Excel, respecting locale, that will appear in Excel as a correctly formatted date.

I did some research with Google but could not find an obvious answer. I considered an ISO format but got mixed information from Google on that one, so am asking the question here.

Comment: `yyyymmdd` is probably the best I've found between software packages.

Comment: I would agree in principle, but if you make the scope of dates 'all time' then what does  20120120 mean - is it 20th Jan 2012 or 20th Dec in the year 0120. I know its a dodgy example but without any kind of format indicator it IS open to interpretation, so fails the unequivocal test.

Comment: Part of it is also *communicating* the chosen date format to your users.

Comment: The ideal, unambiguous format may simply be: "January 20th, 2012"

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad - but that's kind of my point, I want Excel to do the presentation work and respect the locale of the viewer. I am working at the data end of the deal and I just want to know how to give Excel a date that will be perfectly understandable to Excel. Does January 20th 2012 import into a French local with the correct month name, for example?

Comment: Don't know if this is feasible in your worksheets, but would a helper column work? If you created a column with the text value of a date (Mar 7, 2019 being 43531), then in the date column formatted for dates enter a formula referencing that cell? I don't know if users local settings would see a formula differently, allowing for their local settings to display how it should.